# Code to read file prints extra characters

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader

This code reads a text file character by character.
It prints the line number, character number, and the character using different functions.

The `nextChar()` function correctly changes the line and character numbers but still prints the wrong ones before the increment.
For example, this input text should go from "1 : 5 o" to "2 : 0  " then "2 : 1 C". But it prints "1 : 6  " before the "2 : 0  " ...
Also it reads a "?" at the end of the file for some reason.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        String fileName = "";
        System.out.print("Enter the file name: ");
        fileName = scanner.nextLine();
        if(fileName.equalsIgnoreCase("quit") || fileName.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")){System.out.println("Exitting..."); return;}


        while(!fileName.equalsIgnoreCase("quit") || !fileName.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")){
            
            try{
                File file = new File(fileName);
                FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
                br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                
                while(curr != -1){
                    System.out.println(position() + currentChar());
                }

            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                System.out.println("file not found, check file name");
                break;
            }
            
            System.out.print("Enter the file name: ");
            fileName = scanner.nextLine();
            if(fileName.equalsIgnoreCase("quit") || fileName.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")){System.out.println("Exitting..."); return;}       
        }
        scanner.close();

    }

    public static String position(){
        String pos = line + " : " + ch + " ";
        return pos;
    }

    public static void nextChar(BufferedReader br){
        try{
            curr = br.read();
            if(curr==13){
                line++; ch=0;
                System.out.println(line + " : " + ch + "");
                nextChar(br);

            }else{ ch++; }
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("invalid file input");
        }
    }

    public static char currentChar(){
        nextChar(br);
        currChar = (char) curr;
        return currChar;
    }
}
```

Input text:

```
Hello
COSC 455!
```

Output:

```
Enter the file name: input.txt
1 : 1 H
1 : 2 e
1 : 3 l
1 : 4 l
1 : 5 o
2 : 0
1 : 6

2 : 1 C
2 : 2 O
2 : 3 S
2 : 4 C
2 : 5
2 : 6 4
2 : 7 5
2 : 8 5
2 : 9 !
3 : 0
2 : 10

3 : 1 ?
```

Comment: look at the exit condition for the while loop: 
`while(curr != -1){ System.out.println(position() + currentChar()); }`
It looks like the new position and next character are calculated and printed and only then you're going to actually exit the while loop.

Comment: You've got two issues that I can see.  First up, it looks like your lines end with CR + LF (carriage return = 13, then line feed = 10).  You're only checking for the CR; and you're treating the LF like any other character, except that it shows up as being the first character on the next line.  Also, the `println` within `nextChar` gets called BEFORE the `println` on the line where you call `nextChar`; and that makes your outputs appear out of order.

Comment: Oh and the third issue - it looks like you're trying to print the end-of-file marker (the -1) as well, but for some reason, your console shows it as a ? mark.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I removed the println and self-call. the output is not in order, but still includes the extra empty characters listed. Also, what exactly are CR and LF?

Comment: beatmaister: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline . BTW if you want to see _exactly_ what is in a file on Windows, try `format-hex filename` in powershell (or the alias `fhx`).

Comment: Which println did you remove?  Do you understand WHY it was not in order before?  And did you read the bit in parentheses in my earlier comment about Carriage Return (CR) and Line Feed (LF)?

Comment: If you just use [`readLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--) and then step over the characters in the resulting string (`readLine()` auto removes end of line characters) then you should be fine. Increase the line for each line read, and then use the index in the string for the second column.